# ANDROID: Add checkbox after clicking a Button

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I'm trying to do an application that adds me new checkboxes whenever I click a button.
Moreover the new checkbox has to take the name from the texteditor, that I already added.
Could anyone help me?

This is my MyAndroidAppActivity

```
 package com.example.myandroidapp;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.CheckBox;    
 import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

private CheckBox chkIos, chkAndroid, chkWindows;
private Button btnDisplay, btn_add;
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnChkIos();
    addListenerOnButton();

}



public void addListenerOnChkIos() {

    chkIos = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkIos);

    chkIos.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                        "Bro, try Android :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    chkIos = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkIos);
    chkAndroid = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkAndroid);
    chkWindows = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkWindows);
    btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

    btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            result.append("IPhone check : ")
                    .append(chkIos.isChecked());
            result.append("\nAndroid check : ").append(
                    chkAndroid.isChecked());
            result.append("\nWindows Mobile check :").append(
                    chkWindows.isChecked());

            Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this, result.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

}

}
```

and this is main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical" 
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">



  <EditText

   android:id="@+id/edit_message"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:ems="10"
   android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

  <requestFocus />




  <Button
      android:id="@+id/btn_add"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/button_add" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkIos"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/chk_ios" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkAndroid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="@string/chk_android" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkWindows"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/chk_windows" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_display" />
```

Comment: What are you having problem with? You need to be more specific in what the issue is, otherwise people will most likely not try and help you

Comment: if you have fix checkbox... then use visibility..

Comment: Your question is not much clear. You have to briefly explain whatever issue you are facing now. Try to update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add to your layout programmatically after it has been inflated. Add an id to your LinearLayout:

```
android:id ="@+id/layout"
```

Then in OnCreate (after your existing code), get a reference to it and add controls as you wish. For example:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
int lHeight = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
int lWidth = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

ll.addView(cb, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(lHeight, lWidth));
setContentView(ll);
```

You'll actually need to move that code into the click event handler for your button of course. If you want to be able to add more than one checkbox dynamically like this, I think you'll need to manage them in an array. Where you say "checkbox has to take the name from the texteditor" I assume that's the text to show against the checkbox, in which case you'll need to create a TextView at the same time alongside it and set its text from your EditText.

There is then the issue of what happens at a configuration change (i.e. change in the device orientation). That recreates the activity so your dynamic additions will be lost unless you store them in onSaveInstanceState() and then restore them in onRestoreInstanceState() using SharedPreferences.

I hope that helps get you started.